# Compare values as doubles in a JCR-SQL2 query

Tags: comparison, type-conversion, jcr-sql2

I am trying to compare JCR node's `string` properties with a `double` value in JCR-SQL2. But it is comparing the values as `string`s.

For example:

```
SELECT * FROM [nodex] as x  where x.propertyY <= 20.50
```

Here `propertyY` is the `string` in the definition.

I tried this with CASE but it still does not work. Can I compare it as `double` without changing the property definition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Standard JCR-SQL2 has a `CAST(value AS DOUBLE)` expression, but unfortunately it can only be used on the right-hand side of an expression. Yes, JCR-SQL2 is not nearly as flexible as normal SQL.

To my knowledge, there is not really a valid standard way to convert the property value to a double before running the comparison. If you cast the double value to a string, you'll get a lexicographical comparison -- which of course won't really be very useful.

I'm not sure about other implementations, but ModeShape would convert the property value to a double *when the property is a residual property*, since a residual property has no definition and therefore not type. It's quite likely that other implementations would not behave like this.

Comment: Using a string value doesn't work either, even when it's an = comparison.